# Reverse TCP for IOS device?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to develop a react-native application,  sometimes it is saying `cannot connect to the development server`. As I read that executing the react-native project in IOS doesn't needs reverse tcp to accept requests from a development server.

can we do a reverse tcp on an IOS device?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse TCP"? Do you mean the application contacts your React application directly over TCP, as in via an open port?

Comment: For my Application to contact the local API or the Development Server, we use reverse tcp.

Comment: @RadhaManohar did you do `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` after running the server?

Comment: I tried it before and after running the server. Only in few cases it's not connecting.
According to documentation IOS doesn't need any `reverse tcp`. So my doubt is should we do it or donot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adb means "Android Debug Bridge", its not for IOS devices